# Combining Navigation with Controller to PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a PageViewController to manage a series of viewControllers which all use a tableview. As the following picture depicts the PageViewController is a container controller for the PageContentViewControllers

[image: pvc]

After clicking on a tableCell I would like the app to navigate to a detailed view. From what I have read, the proper way to do this is by using a navigationController which is also a container controller.

Through storyboard I have tried putting the NavigationController at both the PageViewController and the PageContentViewController and neither seems to work correctly, I am not sure what other approach I am take.

What is the proper way to combine a PageViewController with a NavigationController if they are both container controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want to structure your app:

1. Embed your PageViewController in a Navigation Controller (select the PageViewController in storyboard and choose Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller)
2. Embed the new Navigation Controller in a Container View within a super controller.

Comment: I attempted the first approach which is what I prefer did not work for me. I will post a more specific question on this site. So I gave you the answer for this, and closed it.

Comment: It does not work for  me too. I can embed in, but got different issues which I provide here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020909/unable-correctly-to-add-navigation-buttons-using-uipageviewcontroller-for-ios