# Unable Correctly to Add Navigation Buttons Using UIPageViewController for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uipageviewcontroller

For my project UIPageViewController could be a good choice, so, I started with the template provided by XCode 6.4 starting new project. I used the template: Page-Based Application which has already the basic implementation of UIPageViewController. The opportunity to scroll the pages is working fine, however, I would like to add the navigation bar as well. After reading the articles on that topic I tried to embed DataViewController into NavigationController (Editor>Embed), and then added the Navigation Bar Button using the storyboard from Interface Builder. However, I cannot see that button when I compile the app. Moreover, it looks that the back navigation works for the pages when you press on the spot where Navigation Bar Button should be located, but button is not visible. Later I found out that the back navigation works not only on that spot but on all left margin of the view. It seems like a bug.

*1. How to make Navigation Bar Back Button visible?*

*2. How to remove that buggy behavior when navigation reacts to the press of all the margin instead of just location of the button?*

Comment: Ad 1: In your storyboard, did you move the arrow pointing to the UIPageViewController (initial view controller) to now point to the navigation controller instead? Alternatively you can check 'initial view controller' in the inspector of the navigation controller. EDIT: scratch that, this would automatically happen if you chose "Embed in", never mind...

Comment: If I move the initial point to the navigation controller, then UIPageViewController does not work, so, I didn't. The initial point is to the Root Controller.

Comment: That's the reason why you don't see the navigation bar. The navigation controller isn't being used/loaded, but the root controller is loaded directly. If you want the navigation controller you have to set it as initial view controller (and embedding the RootViewController in it).

Comment: But I would like to navigate through the pages, not through the root controller items. When I put the initial point to RootViewController, I got navigation bar to the RootViewController, not to the DataViewController (pages), thats is different.

Comment: I actually answered both of your questions.

Comment: Thanks, beyowulf, I need to check your suggestion with objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the navigation controller show up, you need to change:

```
let startingViewController: DataViewController = self.modelController.viewControllerAtIndex(0, storyboard: self.storyboard!)!
```

so that startingViewController is the navigation controller your dataViewController is embedded in. You can do this by changing the storyboard ID of the navigation controller and saying something like:

```
let startingViewController: UIViewController = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavController"))!
```

However this is going to break the template as the rest of the code thinks the starting view controller is a DataViewController, so you will need to change that.

The "buggy behavior" is the standard page controller navigation mechanism when the transitionStyle is set to UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl.